# Applying display properties similar to using ApplySymbologyFromLayer tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, symbology, display

I have created a layer file using ArcGIS 10.3 ModelBuilder.

I have applied symbology to this layer using the ApplySymbologyFromLayer tool in ModelBuilder.

The tool applied the symbology to my created file, but it did not transfer over the display properties (the options found under the 'Display' tab within Layer properties).

In particular, I wanted the selected resampling method (bilinear) from the source layer (the one whose symbology was copied) to be applied to the ModelBuilder layer file the way the symbology was applied. The model actually creates a different layer for each iterated value, so I'd rather not do it manually for each output.

Is there a way to apply source layer display properties to a newly created layer using ArcGIS 10.3 ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do that within ModelBuilder.  A bit of arcpy may be able to do it, but probably easier would be to change your ArcGIS defaults using AdvancedArcMapSettings.

On my PC it's found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\Utilities` - I believe it's in matching folder path in other versions (Desktop10.3, Desktop10.2 etc.)

Select Bilinear Interpolation as your Default resampling mode and hit Apply.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I chose to use the AdvancedArcMapSettings method you suggested. I was able to change the default resampling method to 'Bilinear', I clicked 'Apply', and restarted my computer. I did not receive any error messages but upon viewing Layer properties from subsequent rasters, I can see that 'Nearest Neighbor' is still being used despite 'Bilinear' being checked in the default settings. Any thoughts on why it did not stick?